# Web2py CRUD.read() record created though non-filled condition

Tags: python, crud, web2py

So i worte a function in Web2py to create a record into a table in the Database under a Condition, but Web2py create the record allthough that condition is not filled,

here is the function

```
def buy_product():
    price = price_set(db,auth,'product')
    balance = limit(db,auth,'settings','account_balance')
    if balance !=None:
        if balance < price:
            form=redirect(URL('order'))
        else:
            form=crud.create(db.letter)
            if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
                tax = float(postage(form.vars.tax_type).replace("-","."))
                ##########################
                # I'm talking about this #
                ##########################
                if balance < (price + tax):
                    response.flash='You don\'t have enough balance to buy this product'
                    redirect(URL('not_processed'))
                else:
                    function_1(....)
                    ...
                    ...
                    update_field(db,auth,'settings','account_balance',-price)
                    response.flash='Done'
                    redirect(URL('products'))
                    pass
            elif form.errors:
                response.flash='Error 01'
            else:
                pass
            ###############################
    else:
        form=redirect(URL('settings'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

it's sepposed that when the `Balance < price + tax` the user should be redirected to `not_processed` without creating new record in the database.

but web2py redirect the user to `not_processed` and create the record without executing this part with the entered information from the user. so the user see that he bought something, when it has not processed (see below)

```
        function_1(....)
        ...
        ...
        update_field(db,auth,'settings','account_balance',-price)
        response.flash='Done'
        redirect(URL('products'))
        pass
```

any idea ??

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Crud manages inserts/updates internally and it does not use the form.accepts.

You have two options:

1 - Use SQLFORM

```
    form=SQLFORM(db.letter)
    if form.accepts(request.vars, session):
        tax = float(postage(form.vars.tax_type).replace("-","."))
        ##########################
        # I'm talking about this #
        ##########################
```

2 - Use crud events

```
def myfunction(form):
    # do your stuff here
    # it will be called only when form is accepted

def myotherfunction(form):
    if form.errors:
        #do something here in case of errors
        #it will be called during the form validation

crud.settings.create_onvalidation = myotherfunction
crud.settings.create_onaccept = myfunction
#the above can be:
#crud.create_onaccept = lambda form: myfunction(form)

# define the above events before the creation of the form
form=crud.create(db.letter)
```

Note that SQLFORM is a bit different of crud, SQLFORM expects you to validate the form in form.accepts method, while crud does it internally and uses events as onvalidation, onaccept to custom validations.

Comment: You should be able to also do:
``form = crud.create(db.letter, onvalidation=myvalidationfunction)``
SQLFORM and crud both accept onvalidation arguments. I believe you can then check extra conditions and add errors if these conditions are not met using ``form.errors.field = "Cannot do <something>"``

I only mention it because you may not want a single onvalidation function for all CRUD and you may have a good reason to use CRUD over SQLFORM (SQLFORM also accepts the onvalidation parameter).

See: http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/7#onvalidation
for more